# masking 3 different colors

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask

[image]

So I'm using Adobe Illustrator and I've got three colors, white, and two different shades of gray. when I make a mask with all three colors it turns out great, but when I put the new graphic in front of a white background it doesn't show up even though there's gray in the art. Even when I print the art, it all prints white... Does anyone know how to make sure the grays still show up?

Comment: A screenshot would _really_ help here

Comment: Is the white background the artboard or another graphic?  If it's the latter try bringing the graphic to front `Command + Shift + ]` so it appears on top of the shape. Also agree with @Manly, a screenshot would clear things up considerably.

Comment: i tried the command + shift + ] didnt get much, hope the picture can help a little more?

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding the issue. Are all these "greys" spot color or just tints of black? And part of me thinks, if you are *masking* the art should be black on a white background, not white on white.

Comment: the art has already been masked but those gray spots dont show up on white. and i just put that black background there to show as an example.

Comment: But shouldn't the art (on a white background) be black??? White art on a white background, masked or not, won't be visible. A mask *doesn't* change the color of the original art.

Comment: there isnt just white in it tho, there is also gray and i dont know why the gray isnt showing up, i also print it out on a DTG shirt printer and it prints the graphic but its all white

Comment: You mean there's grey *in the mask* or there's grey in the overall skull shape *being masked*?? Grey in the mask just mean to make that **white** part partially transparent. It honestly sounds like you need black art, and then reverse the mask maybe. Hard to tell without seeing the actual file.

Comment: Of course, you could always just print it reversed.

Comment: Looks to me like the grey is actually semi-transparent white. So you're artwork actually *is* all white but with varying opacity... which over black obviously makes grey

Comment: thats actually what i was starting to think as well, but the opacities are all at 100% and the colors started out as gray. so i guess at this point i dont really know what to ask...

Comment: Could you show us a picture of your layers panel?

Comment: I can put it on here but once I masked the skull with the tire tread and splatter it grouped both layers together

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recreate the issue by using a mask shape filled with white and using it to clip from behind the patterns:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What's happening here is the mask is being clipped by the grays, thus making your gray textures a white, semi-transparent fill. Try bringing the mask shape to the front, `Command + Shift + ]`, before clipping and you'll have a result more like this:

[image]

Comment: That's because you're using the grey to mask the white, which end up with the situation I suggested in my previous comment; various levels of transparent white :)

Comment: @Cai, agreed (that was my upvote on your comment).